# Value of specific item in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a five column list box in a VBA application in Excel. I have gotten how to return the value of a selected item, but is there a way to get the value of the last item in the list? In column two of the list box, I have a date that I want to compare to a preset date. I apologize if this is worded badly.

Say I have a date like 1/13/2014. I want to compare that to the date in column two of the last item in a listbox.

Example Listbox

1, 01/01/2014, example, example, example

2, 01/05/2014, example, example, example

3, 01/07/2014, example, example, example

4, 01/14/2014, example, example, example  <--- I want the date from the second column of this

I just don't know how to return the value of the last record without it being manually selected by the user. Any ideas?

I know that I will probably have to use the ListCount property to get the total number of items in the list box, but I don't know how I can reference that specific index (i.e use listcount to find that the aforementioned list has 4 items and reference the data at lstCases(4,2))

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Using the List property, I could specify a row and column. I have a function that gets the most recent checkpoint (every two weeks from the time that this project started to now) and returns it as a Date.

```
Function getCheckpoint() As Date

 Dim startDate As Date

 startDate = "12/30/2013"

 Do
     startDate = DateAdd("d", 14, startDate)
 Loop Until startDate > Now()

 getCheckpoint = DateAdd("d", -14, startDate)


End Function
```

So I used that to compare as follows:

```
If CDate(frmViewer.lstCases.List(frmViewer.lstCases.ListCount - 1, 1)) < getCheckpoint() Then
    MsgBox ("Please begin a new case")
End If
```

This way, I find the ListCount and subtract one to find the last record and specify the column as 1 to get the second column. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future!